# What is the programatic equivalent of a XML defined spring bean

Tags: java, spring

What is the programatic equivalane to defining a bean like this in xml:

```
<bean id="foo" class="com.bizz.Foo" />
```

Ideally I would like to be able to have spring create that bean, without using XML and without calling `new` and for this to happen within a `@Configuration` type class. For example:

```
@Configuration
public ConfigBar {
  @Bean
  public com.bizz.Foo foo() {
    return /* Programmatic equivalent of <bean id="foo" class="com.bizz.Foo" /> here*/; 
  }
}
```

I don't think `new Foo()` is equivalent:

- as spring is able to pick which constructor to use which may not be the no args constructor.
- and spring is able to inject dependencies, which I don't think will be done here.

I know that spring is doing some reflection to achieve this, however simply stating that is not the answer to this question.

so how can we let spring create the `Foo` bean programmatically letting spring inject dependencies, pick the constructor and perhaps other tasks that spring would normally do when defined in XML?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I have worked it out:

```
@Bean
@Autowired
public Foo foo(AutowireCapableBeanFactory autowireCapableBeanFactory) {
    return autowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(Foo.class);
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The equivalent is `@Component` or any variant thereof such as `@Controller` or `@Service`. So long as your bean is in a package included in the component scan Spring will be able to find your bean at runtime and inject it into other beans.

As an example:

```
@Component
public class Foo {
    //...
}

@Service
public class Bar {

    // Spring will find and inject Foo bean creating it if necessary when 
    // creating the Bar "service" bean 
    @Autowired
    private Foo foo;

    //...
}
```